# Qual a regex para validar somente pontos, números e vírgulas?

Tags: regex

Qual a *regex* para validar somente pontos, números e vírgulas?

Answer (score 9):

Seria esta:

```
^[\d,.?!]+$
```

- O `^` checa desde o inicio
- O `$` checa a partir do final
- O `\d` checa números
- Tudo que estiver dentro de `[...]` será considerado, independente da posição, então pode remover o ? e ! se desejar, como eu não sabia quais pontos desejava adicionei ambos

### JavaScript

Claro que isso apenas irá testar a string e no caso o seu validar dá a entender que é isto o que deseja, se deseja usar com JavaScript pode fazer algo assim:

```js
function validar() {
    var meucampo1 = document.getElementById("meu-campo-1");
    var valido = /^[\d,.?!]+$/.test(meucampo1.value);
    
    alert(valido ? "Validou" : "Não validou");
}
```

```html
Digite algo no campo e aperte em validar:
<input type="text" id="meu-campo-1">
<button onclick="validar()">Validar</button>
```

### HTML5 validação

Se for usar o `pattern="..."` pode aplicar assim:

```html
<form action="" name="form1">
    Digite algo no campo e aperte em validar:
    <input value="" pattern="[\d,.?!]*" title="Please enter allowed characters only.">
    <button>Validar</button> 
</form>
```

Comment: No caso, o ponto precisa ser `\.` já que ele é um elemento do regex, também, pelo que eu entendi, ela não precisa de interrogação, nem exclamação, mas, caso ela queira interrogação, precisa ser `\?`. Fora isso, imagino que ela também queira dar match em uma string vazia, daí seria o caso de trocar o `+` por `*`...

Comment: @FelipeAvelar esta engando, se estiver dentro de `[....]` não precisa de "escapes".

Answer (score 9):

Seria isso:

```
(?:\.|,|[0-9])*
```

Explicação:

- `\.` - Ponto.
- `,` - Vírgula.
- `[0-9]` - Números.
- `|` - Indica escolha.
- `\.|,|[0-9]` - Escolha entre ponto, vírgula ou números.
- `(?: ... )` - Agrupamento sem captura.
- `*` - Repetição do grupo.
- `(?:\.|,|[0-9])*` - Uma repetição de pontos, vírgulas e números.